# How to remove same values based on time using interval?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a data set as following:

```
Name |        Time     |   App 
---------------------------------
Mike  2019-05-10 21:10 chrome.exe
Mike  2019-05-10 21:10 chrome.exe
Mike  2019-05-10 21:12 chrome.exe
John  2019-05-10 18:09 chrome.exe
John  2019-05-10 18:25 chrome.exe
```

My goal is this: I want to combine same apps for each user based on same time or if it is in 5 minute interval and saving only earliest time stamp.

Expected output:

```
Name |        Time     |   App 
---------------------------------
Mike  2019-05-10 21:10 chrome.exe
John  2019-05-10 18:09 chrome.exe
John  2019-05-10 18:25 chrome.exe
```

Mike had run `chrome.exe` 3 times but the interval was <= 5 so we want to count it as once. While John ran `chrome.exe` 2 times but > 5 minute interval so they count as separate runs. I have tried `merge`, `merge_asof` and using `pd.timedelta`.

Comment: if there are three accesses at 18:04, 18:06, and 18:10, do you count them as one or two accesses?

Comment: @QuangHoang good question! Well the idea would be to find the earliest and count from there so 18:04 and 18:06 are one and 18:10 is another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first create example data frame (bit different from yours):

```
data = [('2019-01-01 13:00','John', 'Chrome'),('2019-01-01 13:02','John', 'Chrome'),('2019-01-01 13:06','John', 'Chrome'),('2019-01-01 13:00','Mike', 'Chrome'),('2019-01-01 13:02','Mike', 'Chrome'), ('2019-01-01 13:06','John', 'Chrome')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['Time','Name','App'])
```

You'll need time as index in your dataframe. You can achieve this by:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

Then you can do the following:

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'App', pd.Grouper(freq='5T')]).min() #5T here means 5 minutes
```

(note that this will groupby five minute intervals, starting at full hour, meaning that 13:04 and 13:06 are two different occurences as far as this solution is concerned). You can look up different frequencies to group by http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Result:

```
Name  App     Time               
John  Chrome  2019-01-01 13:00:00    2019-01-01 13:00
              2019-01-01 13:05:00    2019-01-01 13:06
Mike  Chrome  2019-01-01 13:00:00    2019-01-01 13:00
```

Second time is the time you were interested in. The result is pd.Series, you'll likely want to make it a dataframe, or apply `.unstack(level=1)`.

As it was pointed out in the comments, you may not necessarily want to have Time both as an index and new column, then instead of `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)` you might want to do:

```
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
```

Comment: did you mean `first()` instead of `count()`?

Comment: Right, even min()  seems better

Comment: I tried this out and it is what I want. One issue. When doing `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])` It creates a index column as intended but keeps the original column. Now, I find both to be useful. One contains the interval times and the second keeps the original time, but have same column names.

Comment: @MichaelMMeskhi `df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)`.

Comment: This answer will count `18:04`, `18:06`, and `18:10` as three different accesses.

Comment: Using `df.set_index()` outputs error: `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'`

Comment: How about `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)` and then `df.set_index)`?

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
print(df)
m = df.groupby(['Name','App']).Time.apply(lambda x: x.diff().dt.seconds < 5*60) #mask for 5 minutes
df2=df[~m]
print(df2)
```

---

What is `m`. It is the mask of your duplicates that we try to remove, but instead removing it inplace I just assigned a new dataframe without these rows.

---

```
   Name                Time          App
0  Mike 2019-05-10 21:10:00   chrome.exe
1  Mike 2019-05-10 21:10:00   chrome.exe
2  Mike 2019-05-10 21:12:00   chrome.exe
3  John 2019-05-10 18:09:00   chrome.exe
4  John 2019-05-10 18:25:00  chrome.exe7
   Name                Time          App
0  Mike 2019-05-10 21:10:00   chrome.exe
3  John 2019-05-10 18:09:00   chrome.exe
4  John 2019-05-10 18:25:00  chrome.exe7
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get two similar apps but it shows one at 21:28 and one at 21:27.

Comment: The word similar is crucial. The apps need to be exactly the same string in order to remove the record @MichaelMMeskhi.

Comment: It always is the same string